# Look values for email should not show other email id's sharepoint desginer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I need to send email to 2 users in a lookup column in a row. But i dont want both email ids to display for both users when they open the email. How to do this using SharePoint designer workflows?

A particular user to whom the mail has been sent should only see his own id. But I am unable to restrict the lookup. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try BCC'ing the 2 users?

Check this post for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458886/can-i-bcc-an-email-through-sharepoint-designer-workflow